# retry failed job spring batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

I want to define a retry-limit in the xml where if any read/process/write operation fails on a particular item, it will retry for a defined number of times. I get the concept but I'm not getting it to work in the code.

I've had all the appropriate maven support dependencies in the project too.

Here is the xml definition of the step:

```
<batch:step id="step1" >
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="myReader" processor="myProcessor" writer="myWriter" commit-interval="10" **retry-limit="3"**>
                <batch:retryable-exception-classes>
                    <batch:include class="java.lang.ArithmeticException"/>
                </batch:retryable-exception-classes>
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>
```

I'm using a JdbcCursorItemReader to read from the db. In the mapper I'm trying to induce an error manually(java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero ) just to check how this works. My understanding is when this hits the "/by zero" error it should retry 3 times and ultimately fail but I don't see it retiring. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Could you show code where you have configured retry

Comment: Sorry. This was my first question on stack overflow. Corrected the question to show the code.

Comment: WHat do you expect to see exactly (logging messages? did you step through the code?) and what did you see?

Comment: I want to see the some logs saying "attempting to retry" or something. I enabled the debug logging but I don't see anything as such. If it retries, there will be errors again. I want to see those errors in the log.

Answer (score 0):

Retry operates only on the processing and writing phases of a chunk step, not the reading. See [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/75256-retry-in-case-of-a-failed-reading) for some discussion on it :

> On reflection I don't think we should support retry of the ItemReader
>   - the semantics are too hard to define. What is you actual use case here? What does your ItemReader do that is retryable? The problem in
>   general is that ItemReader is a "forward only" contract - it's not
>   possible in general to implement readers that can go back to a
>   previous position in the stream with the interface we have (and we are
>   not going to make it more complicated without a good reason). Given
>   that, if a read() fails, what is the reader supposed to do when we
>   "retry" the operation? Go to the next item is the only possible
>   choice, and that is functionally the same as a skip.

Comment: Got the point. I did the same test in the processor. It fails, but does not retry. It should retry in the processor.

Comment: In that case, can you provide the full code and config ? For me, retry in a failing processor works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

So as I understood, spring does not retry on its own unless you tell it to do so. The retry-limit and all the other params are just the limits and not the actual retry itself.